# Make line break in HTML within cycle For PHP

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop

The first part corresponds to the js code where I call a file that executes the for cycle, but it does not give me the line breaks, putting everything in a column.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#nivel-especialidad").change(function() {
$("#nivel-especialidad option:selected").each(function() {
    Id = $(this).val();
    $.post("../Sql/ArregloRequisitos.php", {Id: Id
        }, function(data){
            $("#requisitos-nivel").html(data);
        });
    });
})
});
</script>
```

In this second part is the HTML code within the For cycle:

```
<?php
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scouts_601_palmira","root","");

$Id_nivel = $_POST['Id'];

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$Id_nivel.'");</script>';

$sql3 = "SELECT Id, Texto FROM Requisitos WHERE Id_nivel =".$Id_nivel."";
$sentencia3 = $conexion -> prepare($sql3);
$sentencia3 -> execute();
$requisitos = $sentencia3 -> fetchAll();

echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 0, $contador=1; $i < count($requisitos); $i++, $contador++) {?>
<td>
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <!--<img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">-->
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"><?php
            echo $requisitos[$i]['Texto'];
            ?></p>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<?php if(($contador%3) == 0) {
    echo "</tr><tr>";
}
}
echo "</tr>";
?>
```

As it is, the code prints everything in a single column, one div on the other. What I want is that as the if condition says at the end, it is to show a div side by side and when three (columns) have already been shown, the line break is made, and this repeatedly until all the data is printed obtained from the BD.

I thank you in advance for any solution to this problem.

Currently it looks like this:
[image]
I want it to look like this:
[image]
I think, here is the inconvenient:
[image]

Comment: Not your current issue BUT this code is open to SQL and XSS injections. You should parameterize your queries and escape the user output before sending it out to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for comment. You do not have to apply what you told me.

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: Look the new image.

Comment: are you sure that html comes from that php code, I don't see any of the `td`s and they should be there for every `div.cart`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, now it is running normally. i delete this code line echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$Id_nivel.'");</script>';